# Spring Security Combining oauth2 and api key filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

currently I'm facing the problem of allowing a user to authorize to a REST Api with either an X-API-KEY header **or** an oauth2 jwt token.

The current security config looks like this:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.addFilterBefore(apiKeyAuthFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(h -> h.httpStrictTransportSecurity(c -> c.requestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE)));

        http.oauth2ResourceServer(server -> server.jwt(jwt ->
                        jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(
                                jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter()).decoder(jwtDecoder())
                )
        );

        return http.build();
    }
```

The problem I have is that even though I provide a valid jwt and the oauth2ResourceServer is fine it still triggers the apiKeyFilter and then failes as the header is not set.

I read a lot of stuff regarding multi authentication but spring security is hard to get. Maybe you have an idea or some ressources to look up.

Comment: Please provide the code for the apiKeyAuthFilter

Comment: are they request to the same endpoint? or else just set up 2 different filter chains that handles different endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to make `apiKeyAuthFilter` extend `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and to provide a suitable `RequestHeaderRequestMatcher`. This should then only apply any authentication you've added in `attemptAuthentication` if the header is present.

```
public class ApiKeyAuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  public ApiKeyAuthFilter() {
    super(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("X-API-KEY"));
  }
```